# The process cannot access the file 'info1.xml'

Tags: c#

When I run this code (I want to compress recursively including the files in current directory), I have an error: 'The process cannot access the file 'C:.........\info1.xml'.

This is the code that I am using:

```
public static void CompressFiles(string directory)
    {
        string infoFile = "info.xml";

        if (File.Exists(@"info.xml"))
            infoFile = "info1.xml";
        else if (File.Exists(@"info1.xml"))
            infoFile = "info2.xml";
        else if (File.Exists(@"info2.xml"))
            infoFile = "info3.xml";
        else if (File.Exists(@"info3.xml"))
            infoFile = "info4.xml";

        StreamWriter outputCacheMeta = new StreamWriter(infoFile);

        outputCacheMeta.WriteLine(@"    <?xml version='1.0' encoding='utf-8'?>");
        outputCacheMeta.WriteLine(@"    <CacheInfo>");

        var dirfiles = Directory.GetFiles(directory);

        foreach (var fileName in dirfiles.Where(fileName => !fileName.Contains("info")
                                                         && !fileName.Contains("BuildCacheMeta")
                                                         && !fileName.Contains(".xz")
                                                         && !fileName.Contains(".xml")))
        {
            Console.WriteLine(string.Format("Compressing file: '{0}'", fileName.ToString()));

            ProcessStartInfo startInfo = new ProcessStartInfo();
            startInfo.FileName = "xz.exe";
            startInfo.Arguments = "-k -z " + fileName;
            startInfo.CreateNoWindow = true;
            startInfo.WindowStyle = ProcessWindowStyle.Hidden;

            using (Process p = Process.Start(startInfo))
            {
                while (!p.HasExited)
                {
                    Thread.Sleep(300);
                }
            }

            FileInfo inFile = new FileInfo(fileName.ToString());
            //FileInfo outFile = new FileInfo(Path.Combine(Directory.GetCurrentDirectory(), "\\", filena));
            FileInfo outFile = new FileInfo(fileName.ToString() + ".xz");

            var finalString = "     <ContentFile Name=\"" + fileName.ToString() + "\" Size=\"" + inFile.Length.ToString() + "\" SHA1Hash=\"" + HashCalc.GetSHA1Hash(fileName).ToString() + "\" CompressedSize=\"" + outFile.Length.ToString() + "\" />\n";

            inFile.Delete();
        }

        outputCacheMeta.WriteLine("     </CacheInfo>");
        outputCacheMeta.Flush();
    }

    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var directories = Directory.GetDirectories(Directory.GetCurrentDirectory());
        var currentDirectory = Directory.GetCurrentDirectory();

        CompressFiles(currentDirectory);

        foreach (var dir in directories)
        {
            CompressFiles(dir);

            var subdirectories = Directory.GetDirectories(dir);

            foreach (var subdir in subdirectories)
            {
                CompressFiles(subdir);
            }
        }
    }
```

Thanks!

Comment: In which line? It's not complete code? What "finalString" is for?! BTW why don't you just use WaitForExit()?

Comment: In line: StreamWriter outputCacheMeta = new StreamWriter(infoFile);

Comment: You don't close it...put that line in an "using" statement, file stream will be closed and next call won't fail (but check your algorithm because you don't append so after 4 files you'll overwrite infoX.xml)